# php function and html

Tags: php, html, function

When I create elements in some places I will return html code.  Is it better to have the function return an array and then create the html for each item on the list or table after or to have the html as part of the function?

e.g.

```
function failedScansTable($eventId)
{
    echo "<table class='basic-table'>";
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT total_errors FROM errors WHERE id_event = $eventId");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
        {
            $totalErrors = $row['total_errors'];
            echo "<tr class='basic-table-total'><th colspan='3'>Total Rejected Scans</th><th>$totalErrors</th></tr>";
        }
    echo "</table>";
}
```

Comment: i think function always return some values is the good thing. Assign that html to a variable and return the variable at the end.

Comment: I think it will be better to function return an array and then create a html out of it ... because according to me it will make things much easier to understand..

Comment: In my opinion it depends on what you are using it for. If the table is shown in one place and one place only, return array. If you are displaying the table all over the place, may be with different data, use it with html.

Comment: Don't use `mysql_` functions they are deprecated. Use PDO instead.

Comment: thanks for the input rid.  if you have any info as to how it can be improved I'm happy to hear it as I am learning but a statement with no info beyond that is not really of much use

Comment: Thanks Mario, I do use it in a number of places so will stick with the html.  Also, thanks sann.  Will look into PDO now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The function should generally return something instead of `echo`-ing
- The function should generally not generate HTML code, but rather return data (such as an array of values) than can then be used in views (specific parts of the application that only generate HTML). Take a look at the [Model-View-Controller architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) to get an idea of how to separate concerns.
- PHP was created to be used as a templating language as well, so instead of generating HTML by string concatenation, you should use something like:

  ```
  <table>
      <?php foreach (failedScansTable() as $entry): ?>
          <tr> ... </tr>
      <?php endforeach ?>
  </table>
  ```
- You should not use `mysql_*` functions anymore, since they are officially deprecated. Consider [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) instead.
- Always escape parts that you append to your code.

  - You should escape `$eventId` before appending it to the SQL code (`mysql_real_escape_string()` or, much better, [PDO](http://php.net/pdo))
  - You should escape `$totalErrors` before appending it to the HTML code ([`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars))

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I'm looking into the PDO.  I would normally check the string being added but it is an example rather than a function I would have anyone other than myself using.  Why no echoing or html code though?  is it due to functionality?  I will only be using this function to create a table so the info won't be used anywhere else.

Comment: @AlanDoolan, no matter where the data comes from, you should always escape it. Even if you create the data yourself, it's not uncommon to need an apostrophe in a string, which would result in a SQL syntax error, or a less than sign which would not produce the desired result in HTML. So whatever you do, as long as you're concatenating something from one language to another, don't necessarily check it, but always escape it.

Comment: @AlanDoolan, about `echo`-ing, if you go down this road, your application will end up being composed a certain way, which will make it extremely hard to refactor later. If this is the only function you will ever use to generate HTML, although it's not particularly pretty, it should do the trick, but if you plan on extending the app even just a bit, this won't work in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

Better, Try this

```
function failedScansTable($eventId)
{
     $string= "<table class='basic-table'>";
     $sql = mysql_query("SELECT total_errors FROM errors WHERE id_event = $eventId");
     while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
     {
        $totalErrors = $row['total_errors'];
        $string.= "<tr class='basic-table-total'><th colspan='3'>Total Rejected Scans</th><th>$totalErrors</th></tr>";
     }
     $string.= "</table>";
     return array('html'=>$string, 'totalError'=>$totalErrors);
}
```

Comment: Hi Tapas, thanks for the code.  What is the advantage of doing it this way?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
function failedScansTable($eventId)

{

$html = "<table class='basic-table'>";

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT total_errors FROM errors WHERE id_event = $eventId");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))

    {

        $totalErrors = $row['total_errors'];

        $html.="<tr class='basic-table-total'><th colspan='3'>Total Rejected Scans</th><th>$totalErrors</th></tr>";

    }

$html.="</table>";

return $html;

}
```

Comment: I think $totalErrors is also needed here. So you should return both.

Comment: what is the advantage of returning it as a var?

Answer (score 0):

If your code is going to grow bigger, it's better to follow a design pattern, such as [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).

Therefore it's better to separate your model from your view. The array is your data model; and the html, which is how you present your data, is the view.

Comment: what is the advantage other than organisation on my side that going with this method will provide?  will it function better overall?

Comment: That is really subjective. MVC is not always the most approriate method of doing things. I do however agree that it's good practise to have the data access separated from the output. It's good to use a design pattern, wether it's MVC or Multitier architecture or something else that separates data from the view logic

Comment: @AlanDoolan the advantage is the data and how you present it is decoupled. If for instance you want to change how it looks, you don't need to touch your data model, but just change your view. Also if you want to test your code, it's much easier to test them separately.

Comment: @Mark I agree with you. MVC itself has some many variations, too. It's best to use a pattern that suits.